# Kill async task c#, wpf

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

In my application i have class PrimaryViewModel (abstract) and every ViewModel inherit from it. 
To get data every X seconds i have written following virtual method

```
 protected virtual async void RunSynchronizeTask()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(RefreshTime);
                if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - LastSyncrhonization.TimeOfDay > RefreshTime)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
                    {
                        GetDataAndRefreshUI();
                    });
                    LastSyncrhonization = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So every viewModel has it owns method and it own task which will get data from DB and refresh binded controls (for example messageViewModel refresh messages list every 0.5 seconds)

but problem is that when i run released application (no debug mode, just build as release and open exe) and close, the app will close, but this async task is still working (i see it in task manager)

What should i do?
How to assign this task to something, i cannot do :
var task = await.Task.Run(...)

If i could i would create some static list with referencses to theses tasks and on application close i would kill them or sth...

Comment: Well you could do something like this: A) Move your code to async function that returns `Task` not `void`. B) Use some static bool flag or (even better) an instance of `CancellationToken` in `while(true)` condition. C) In your main thread - allow some time for completion of Tasks before closing the app

Comment: I'd just using Microsoft's Reactive Framework - then you can do this: `IDisposable subscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)).ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(_ => GetDataAndRefreshUI());`. Calling `subscription.Dispose()` will stop it cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

You go from an `async void` to a `Task.Run()` , which is doubling up.
And then you do the actual work in a `Dispatcher.Invoke()`

The only thing that is truly async (concurrent) here is the `Thread.Sleep()`.

So you can replace all this with a DispatcherTimer. That should cure your halting problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fabian!
 works great with cancellation token :

```
  protected virtual async void RunSynchronizeTask()
        {
            var cancelationToken = new CancellationToken();
            App.TaskToDisposeTokens.Add(cancelationToken);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try { 
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(RefreshTime);
                    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - LastSyncrhonization.TimeOfDay > RefreshTime)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
                        {
                            GetDataAndRefreshUI();
                        });
                        LastSyncrhonization = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
                }
                catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
            }, cancelationToken);

        }
```

App.Cs

```
 private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var token in TaskToDisposeTokens)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
```

and in App.Xaml

```
<Application x:Class="RandevouWpfClient.App"
           ...
             Exit="Application_Exit">
```

Comment: You do realize that `Dispatcher.Invoke()` executes stuff on the main UI thread? So this whole setup is just a big, expensive and complicated timer.